# Select query with lock not working

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to read a row from a table with a lock so that others can not do any read operation on that table.

Here is my query that I am running from the `psql` console with a `30 seconds` of sleep.

```
select * from TABLE_NAME for update; SELECT pg_sleep(30);
```

I also tried `nowait`:

```
select * from TABLE_NAME for update nowait; SELECT pg_sleep(30);
```

My table has `only one row` for the test purpose, so where condition is not required here.

Now, from another `psql` console I am doing a `select` operation on the same table(within  the 30 seconds), but I am still able to read the records.

My question is, why this locking is not working? Or Its not the right way to do it? Can someone guide me a bit?

Comment: You are locking it for update not for reading. Try updating it.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto I used, its updating. Basically I want to prevent from `read` by others. But for this test purpose locking for any kind of operations will do for me.

Comment: You cannot block read requests unless you lock the complete table (using `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` mode)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I just want to simulate locking. For example I'll enable lock for 30 seconds from one console, and want to get error from other console for that lock. Is there any way to do it? If it is using `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` mode, I have no problem with it.

Comment: What does that mean, that you want to simulate locking?  Are you trying to learn about how locking in PostgreSQL works, or do you have a specific user-visible locking need which you wish to implement?

Comment: @jjanes Just want to simulate locking. So that I can fail my application. That's different issue. Just want to see it using two console :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your `SELECT FOR UPDATE` should be wrapped in a transaction to be effective.

When typing this in a single line in `psql`:

```
select * from TABLE_NAME for update; SELECT pg_sleep(30);
```

it gets broken down into two sql statements executed separately, so the locking effect of `FOR UPDATE` is lost before the `pg_sleep` even starts.

Try:

```
 BEGIN; select * from TABLE_NAME for update; SELECT pg_sleep(30); END;
```

and in the other session:

```
select * from TABLE_NAME for update;
```

to see the second session being blocked for 30 seconds.

Comment: You are right. Your `BEGIN` `END` wrapping solved it.